# Change richtext box text color without selecting

Tags: c#

I've been trying to color some words in my textbox like "hi", "bye"

I've tried stuff like:

```
int stIndex = 0;
stIndex = richTextBox1.Find(wh, stIndex, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
while (stIndex != -1)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText == wh)
    {
        richTextBox1.SelectionLength = wh.Length;
        richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    stIndex = richTextBox1.Find(wh, stIndex + 1, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase);
}
```

but that selects the words thus moving the cursor is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why set `stIndex` to 0, then immediately change the value? Use `int stIndex = richTextBox1.Find(wh, 0, RichTextBoxFinds.MatchCase)`

Comment: Try looking at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150634/c-changing-font-style-of-winform-richtextbox-without-selecting-the-text) and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186154/rich-text-box-how-to-highlight-text-block-without-select)